# zxing activity to scan QR code embedded

Tags: java, android, zxing, qr-code

Here I am expecting that zxing-core has some activity that can be launched from other app and that is how they integrate without having to launch some 3rd party app to scan QR code

I tried adding

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
```

to `build.gradle` file I can see these jars are imported, however I don't see this class being present in jar

```
com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
```

and in side jar

```
$ unzip -l ./modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.zxing/core/3.1.0/908e18674f895e3e1fa8f4a954b8c637a23d2801/core-3.1.0.jar | grep -i 'activity'
```

I don't see that class part of core module [Here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client)

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

I am using this approach:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Just to make sure: my expectation is that the activity is part of library for the usecase when user wants to use embedded scanner instead of delegating scanning to other app

Comment: I went through this same process. You'll have to create your own activity that implements the library

Comment: Use ZBAr https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar

Comment: Thank you @Neil, you mean create activity similar to `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity` in your source ?

Comment: I'll try and give an example.

Answer (score 8):

**This is a very long answer so read carefully to make sure that you don't miss anything.**

You can see an example project on my [Github Repo](https://github.com/NeilHogg69/Android-Tutorials/tree/master/ZxingScannerIntegration)

Okay so first off you have to add the core zxing library jar to your libs folder in your project directory. You will also have to create a package for the zxing classes. See below

```
foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing
foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.view
```

In the first package `foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing` you add the following classes

---

**CameraManager.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource;

/**
 * Camera manager
 */
public class CameraManager {
    /**
     * Fraction of bounds size in view
     */
    private static final double BOUNDS_FRACTION = 0.6;
    /**
     * Fraction of height of bounds in view
     */
    private static final double VERTICAL_HEIGHT_FRACTION = 0.3;

    /**
     * Camera instance
     */
    private Camera camera;
    /**
     * Id of camera instance
     */
    private int cameraId;
    /**
     * Current orientation of camera
     * Possible values : 0, 90, 180, 270
     */
    private int orientation;

    public CameraManager() {
        this.camera = getCameraInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for camera
     *
     * @return camera instance, if it has been initialized
     */
    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }

    /**
     * Starts preview of camera, if it has been initialized
     */
    public synchronized void startPreview() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stops preview of camera, if it has been initialized
     */
    public synchronized void stopPreview() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Release camera, if it has been initialized
     */
    public synchronized void release() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return if camera has been initialized<br/>( <code>camera != null</code> )
     */
    public synchronized boolean hasCamera() {
        return camera != null;
    }

    /**
     * @return bounding rect for ui
     */
    public final synchronized Rect getBoundingRectUi(int uiWidth, int uiHeight) {
        double heightFraction = BOUNDS_FRACTION;
        double widthFraction = BOUNDS_FRACTION;
        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            heightFraction = VERTICAL_HEIGHT_FRACTION;
        }

        Log.d("CameraManager", "dimsUI[" + uiWidth + ", " + uiHeight + "]");

        int height = (int) (uiHeight * heightFraction);
        int width = (int) (uiWidth * widthFraction);
        int left = (int) (uiWidth * ((1 - widthFraction) / 2));
        int top = (int) (uiHeight * ((1 - heightFraction) / 2));
        int right = left + width;
        int bottom = top + height;

        return new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    /**
     * @return bounding rect for camera
     */
    public final synchronized Rect getBoundingRect() {
        if (camera != null) {
            Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            int previewHeight = previewSize.height;
            int previewWidth = previewSize.width;

            double heightFraction = BOUNDS_FRACTION;
            double widthFraction = BOUNDS_FRACTION;
            if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
                widthFraction = VERTICAL_HEIGHT_FRACTION;
            }
            Log.d("CameraManager", "dimsPrev[" + previewWidth + ", " + previewHeight + "]");

            int height = (int) (previewHeight * heightFraction);
            int width = (int) (previewWidth * widthFraction);
            int left = (int) (previewWidth * ((1 - widthFraction) / 2));
            int top = (int) (previewHeight * ((1 - heightFraction) / 2));
            int right = left + width;
            int bottom = top + height;

            return new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * executes <br/> <code>camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(callback)</code> if <br/>
     * <code>camera != null</code>
     * @param callback callback to provide
     */
    public synchronized void requestNextFrame(Camera.PreviewCallback callback) {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(callback);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A factory method to build the appropriate LuminanceSource object based on the format
     * of the preview buffers, as described by Camera.Parameters.
     *
     * @param data   A preview frame.
     * @param width  The width of the image.
     * @param height The height of the image.
     * @return A PlanarYUVLuminanceSource instance.
     */
    public synchronized PlanarYUVLuminanceSource buildLuminanceSource(byte[] data, int width, int height, Rect boundingRect) {
        switch (orientation) {
            case 0:
                //data = flip(data);
                break;
            case 90:
                rotate90(data, width, height);
                return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, height, width, boundingRect.top, boundingRect.left,
                        boundingRect.height(), boundingRect.width(), false);

            case 180:
                break;
            case 270:
                rotate90(data, width, height);
                break;
        }

        return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, boundingRect.left, boundingRect.top,
                boundingRect.width(), boundingRect.height(), false);
    }

    /**
     * Rotates image data
     * @param data raw image data
     * @param width width of image
     * @param height height of image
     */
    public void rotate90(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
        int length = height * width;
        int lengthDec = length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        do {
            int k = (i * height) % lengthDec;
            while (k > i) k = (height * k) % lengthDec;
            if (k != i) swap(data, k, i);
        } while (++i <= (length - 2));
    }

    /**
     * Sets camera display orientation depending on current activity orientation
     * @param activity activity, which holds camera preview
     */
    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        orientation = result;
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }


    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */
    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            cameraId = 0;
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
            p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
            c.setParameters(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(CameraManager.class.getSimpleName(), "Camera error", e);
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    /**
     * Swaps two elements in array
     * @param data array
     * @param k first element to swap
     * @param i second element to swap
     */
    private static void swap(byte[] data, int k, int i) {
        byte temp = data[k];
        data[k] = data[i];
        data[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

---

**CaptureHandler.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 */
public class CaptureHandler extends Handler {
    public static final String DECODED_DATA = "decoded_data";
    private CameraManager cameraManager;
    private Context context;
    private OnDecodedCallback callback;

    public CaptureHandler(CameraManager cameraManager, Context context, OnDecodedCallback callback) {
        this.cameraManager = cameraManager;
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case R.id.decoded:
                String data = msg.getData().getString(DECODED_DATA);
                Toast.makeText(context, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (callback != null){
                    callback.onDecoded(data);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.decode_failed:
                //getting new frame
                cameraManager.requestNextFrame(new PreviewCallback(this, cameraManager));
                break;
        }
    }

    public static interface OnDecodedCallback {
        void onDecoded(String decodedData);
    }
}
```

---

**PreviewCallback.java**

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.zxing.*;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.R;

/**
 * Camera preview callback
 */
public class PreviewCallback implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private static final String TAG = PreviewCallback.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Xzing multi format reader
     */
    private final MultiFormatReader multiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();
    /**
     * Handler to send messages
     *
     * @see CaptureHandler
     */
    private Handler handler;
    /**
     * Camera manager
     */
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    public PreviewCallback(Handler handler, CameraManager cameraManager) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.cameraManager = cameraManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        try {
            Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            new DecodeAsyncTask(previewSize.width, previewSize.height).execute(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Random errors from zxing
        }
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronous task for decoding and finding barcode
     */
    private class DecodeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Result> {
        /**
         * Width of image
         */
        private int width;
        /**
         * Height of image
         */
        private int height;

        /**
         * @param width  Width of image
         * @param height Height of image
         */
        private DecodeAsyncTask(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Decode success.");
                if (handler != null) {
                    Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.decoded);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(CaptureHandler.DECODED_DATA, result.toString());
                    message.setData(bundle);
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Decode fail.");
                if (handler != null) {
                    Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.decode_failed);
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Result doInBackground(byte[]... datas) {
            if (!cameraManager.hasCamera()) {
                return null;
            }
            Result rawResult = null;
            final PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source =
                    cameraManager.buildLuminanceSource(datas[0], width,
                            height, cameraManager.getBoundingRect());
            if (source != null) {
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                try {
                    rawResult = multiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
                } catch (Exception re) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR", re);
                } finally {
                    multiFormatReader.reset();
                }
            }

            return rawResult;
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Then***
After adding those three classes to the `foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing` package, you have to add the following classes to the `foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.view` package

---

**BoundingView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.CameraManager;

/**
 * View for displaying bounds for active camera region
 */
public class BoundingView extends View {
    /**
     * Camera manager
     */
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    public BoundingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BoundingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Sets camera manger
     * @param cameraManager
     */
    public void setCameraManager(CameraManager cameraManager) {
        this.cameraManager = cameraManager;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (cameraManager != null) {
             Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
             paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));

//             Rect boundingRect = cameraManager.getBoundingRectUi(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
             Rect boundingRect = cameraManager.getBoundingRect();
             canvas.drawRect(boundingRect, paint);

             paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
             paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#44FF0000"));
             paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
             int incY = (canvas.getHeight() - boundingRect.height())/2;
             int incX = (canvas.getWidth() - boundingRect.width())/2;

             int y = (boundingRect.height()/2) + incY;
             int x = boundingRect.width() + incX;
             canvas.drawLine(incX, y, x, y, paint);
             canvas.drawRect(new Rect(incX, boundingRect.top, x, boundingRect.bottom), paint);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**CameraPreviewView.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.CameraManager;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Camera preview view. Shows camera preview data
 */
public class CameraPreviewView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = CameraPreviewView.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Surface holder for camera preview data
     */
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    /**
     * Camera manager
     */
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    public CameraPreviewView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public CameraPreviewView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for camera manager
     * @param cameraManager camera manager to set
     */
    public void setCameraManager(CameraManager cameraManager) {
        this.cameraManager = cameraManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            cameraManager.setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity) getContext());
            cameraManager.getCamera().setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            cameraManager.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // empty. Taking care of releasing the Camera preview in activity.
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            cameraManager.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            cameraManager.setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity) getContext());
            cameraManager.getCamera().setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            cameraManager.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

---

When that is done you can start with the implementation `Activity`. **Just note that some of the classes require you to create id's for certain states, FOR EXAMPLE**

```
R.id.decode_failed
```

You need to create these ids in a resource folder within your app. Next we can get to the implementation `Activity`.

---

**CaptureActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import foo.bar.yourpackagename.R;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.CameraManager;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.CaptureHandler;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.PreviewCallback;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.view.BoundingView;
import foo.bar.yourpackagename.zxing.view.CameraPreviewView;

/**
 * Capture activity (camera barcode activity)
 */
public class CaptureActivity extends Activity {
    public static String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER;

    /**
     * Camera preview view
     */
    private CameraPreviewView cameraPreview;
    /**
     * Camera manager
     */
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    /**
     * Capture handler
     */
    private Handler captureHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(getContentView());

        initializeCamera();
        initializeCameraPreview();
        initializeBoundingView();
    }

    private View getContentView() {
        RelativeLayout contentView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        contentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        contentView.addView(getBoundingView());
        contentView.addView(getCameraPreviewView());

        return contentView;
    }

    private CameraPreviewView getCameraPreviewView() {
        //This is the camera SurfaceView
        CameraPreviewView camPreview = new CameraPreviewView(this);
        camPreview.setId(R.id.camera_preview);
        camPreview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return camPreview;
    }

    private BoundingView getBoundingView() {
        //Displays the bounding content
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        BoundingView boundingView = new BoundingView(this);
        boundingView.setId(R.id.bounding_view);
        boundingView.setLayoutParams(params);

        return boundingView;
    }

    private void initializeCamera() {
        // Create an instance of Camera
        cameraManager = new CameraManager();
        captureHandler = new CaptureHandler(cameraManager, this, new OnDecoded());

        //requesting next frame for decoding
        cameraManager.requestNextFrame(new PreviewCallback(captureHandler, cameraManager));
    }

    private void initializeCameraPreview() {
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        cameraPreview = (CameraPreviewView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        cameraPreview.setCameraManager(cameraManager);
    }

    private void initializeBoundingView() {
        //Set the cameraManager to the bounding view
        ((BoundingView) findViewById(R.id.bounding_view)).setCameraManager(cameraManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //We don't want the cameraManager to take up unneeded 
        //resources so we release it from memory onPause
        cameraManager.release();
    }

    /**
     * This handles the decoded content from the Zxing framework. As
     * soon as the framework has completed the decoding process the CaptureHandler
     * will pass it back via this listener for you to handle it further.
     *
     */
    private class OnDecoded implements CaptureHandler.OnDecodedCallback {
        @Override
        public void onDecoded(String decodedData) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, decodedData);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

---

To start the activity you will simply call

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class));
```

Also remember to add the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

And your `Activity`

```
<activity
    android:name=".CaptureActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To the `Manifest`!

If you implement all these classes correctly you should then be able to start scanning barcodes.

Comment: I see error in CaptureActivity.getContentView - when you add bounding view before camera view, it's not visible (drawn behind camera output). Flip them. Also drawing transparent rect in BoundingView seems wrong.